# QT Application crashes using QSettings instance via qApp->property

Tags: c++, qt

Aloha,

Im developing a small "ServerManager" for myself using QT (C++).
Anything worked till this point:

I use `QSettings` to store all relevant Settings (like Server, installed Plugins and so on).

As I didn't want to instanciate the `QSettings` class everywhere I have to use it, i thought i could try to instanciate it one time in the `main.cpp` and make it available using the `qApp->setProperty()` method.

How i setup the `QSettings` class:

`QSettings* Settings = new QSettings(".\\Settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);`

How i "publish" it:

`qApp->setProperty("Settings", QVariant::fromValue<QSettings*>(Settings));`

And finally. If i use it like this:

```
QSettings* Settings = qApp->property("Settings").value<QSettings*>();
Settings->beginGroup("Servers");
```

The whole application crashed with an `SIGSEGV` signal (Segmentation fault).

Stacktrace: [Stacktrace http://host-it.tk/Upload/53ab11da0d706/37.PNG](http://host-it.tk/Upload/53ab11da0d706/37.PNG)

I really got no clue why this happens.
Maybe the solution is obvious, but this is my "first real" Application.

It seems like I got the well known "tunnel view".

Thanks for your time!

Relevant code parts: http://pastebin.com/VzZ9uuJi

QT-Version: 5.2.1

Comment: Use your debugger (or `qDebug`/`printf`/`cout` statements) to check if the pointer value returned by the `value()` call matches the pointer value returned by `new`.

Comment: First of all. Thanks for your answer(s):

QT: Version 5.2.1
Debugger: That was an brilliant idea! After I try to receive the Instance the Pointer is 0 @andrew-medico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a QSettings* is not a usual QVariant type, you would have to declare it.

```
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSettings*);
```

This is not the usual way to share QSettings, though. Since it is in INI format, consider just passing the location to the INI file *with absolute paths* instead:

```
    QFileInfo path(".\\Settings.ini");
    qApp->setProperty("SettingsLocation", path.absoluteFilePath());
```

Then later:

```
    QSettings Settings(qApp->property("SettingsLocation").toString(), QSettings::IniFormat);
    Settings.beginGroup("Servers");
```